# Finding index in array based on DIV text

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexing

I have a DIV which has text in it:

```
<div id="x">
  divText
</div>
```

I have a "header row" like this:

```
var headerRow = ["wrong","wrongAgain","divText"];
```

I also have an array like this:

```
var theArray = [["blah","blah","0"]["notIt","blahblah","1"],["unrelated","dontLook","0"]];
```

I want to find the index in theArray (2) based on the text within the div:

```
var theDiv = x.innerHTML;
for (i=0; i < headerRow.length; i++){
    if (headerRow[i] == theDiv){        <--never works
    if (headerRow[i] == x.innerHTML) {  <---never works
    if (headerRow[i] == "divText") {     <--works (i = 2)
}
```

How can I find the index based on the innerHTML of a div / variable (first two cases above)? Thanks!

Comment: use x.text()  instead innerHTML  $("#x).text() <--- will work

Comment: I am sure this is duplicated question. search for `indexOf`

Comment: Try innerText, instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You are using innerHTML where as which returns content of HTML element including spaces and new lines.Instead use innerText or use methods **trim** method on either innerHTML or textContent.

In your case the comparision is not successful because the text that you are extracting using innerHTML contains spaces and newline.

> Note:If element ID is valid identifier it can be used directly as
>   **window.elementid**  or just **elementid** but it's best practice to use getElementByID

```
var x = document.getElementById('x')  
var theDiv = x.innerHTML.trim();
for (i=0; i < headerRow.length; i++){
    if (headerRow[i] == theDiv) {
              // your codes goes here
              console.log('works')
    }
}
```

or You can use

```
var theDiv = x.innerText
```

or

```
var theDiv = x.textContent.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="x">
    divText
</div>


<script>
    
    var headerRow = ["wrong","wrongAgain","divText"];
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
    console.log(theDiv);
    for (i=0; i < headerRow.length; i++){
        if (headerRow[i] == theDiv.trim()){
            console.log(headerRow.indexOf(headerRow[i]));
            console.log(i);
            
        }
        
    }
        
</script>
```

Your if comparison doesn't work because of extra whitespace/new line in the div's innerHTML text. Thus you need to trim the string before comparing it with the contents of the header row array. Note that you can either use the indexOf method to get the index of the matching element, or you can just use the current value of i, which would also correspond to the index of that element. Hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score -1):

To get the text from div you should get element by id first

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

It will work with 1sth array, and the 2nd nested array can be flattened first

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat